# Build error on Appveyor with newest ASP.NET 5

Tags: appveyor

I'm trying to build an ASP.NET 5 web api and build it on Appveyor. I get this error:

Build started
git clone -q --branch=master https://github.com/nikolaschou/TodolistService01.git C:\projects\todolistservice01
git checkout -qf 3c97bb95ecf54662069b6ae8fa25a60f598a564d
msbuild "TodolistService.sln" /verbosity:minimal /logger:"C:\Program Files\AppVeyor\BuildAgent\Appveyor.MSBuildLogger.dll"
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 14.0.24720.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Cannot find DNX runtime dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update1 in the folder: C:\Users\appveyor.dnx\runtimes
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DNX\Microsoft.DNX.targets(126,5): error : The Dnx Runtime package needs to be installed. See output window for more details. [C:\projects\todolistservice01\src\TodolistService\TodolistService.xproj]
Command exited with code 1

This project is based on .NET framework 4.6.1 and ASP.NET 5. The references are DNX 4.5.1 and DNX Core 5.0.

Feel free to reproduce the error by building this public repository: 
https://github.com/nikolaschou/TodolistService01

Can anyone explain why it fails? Is Appveyor not yet ready for these new versions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, you have to do two things:

- install .NET framework
- restore packages

This is `appveyor.yml` to build your project:

```
os: Visual Studio 2015

install:
- dnvm upgrade -r clr
- dnu restore

build:
  verbosity: minimal
```

Build results: https://ci.appveyor.com/project/FeodorFitsner/todolistservice01

Comment: @NikolaSchou if this worked you should accept it as the answer. This allows other people to easily know it's the right correct answer.

Comment: Sure, I did it just now.

Answer (score 1):

Also, you may need to select right version in your `global.json`:

```
{
    "sdk": {
        "version": "1.0.0-rc1-final"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx will try that as well and see if it makes a difference.